# bad internet connection and PFQueryCollectionViewController

Tags: parse-platform

I was testing my app and I noticed this error message popping up from the `PFQueryCollectionViewController`:

```
2015-07-06 21:40:58.445 Noms[320:29335] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
2015-07-06 21:40:58.446 Noms[320:29335] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.604623 seconds.
```

This was expected, since my phone was not connected to the internet. However, I want to detect this error and handle it myself, rather having the endless loading scroll on the screen. Looking at the documentation didn't yield any variables that I thought could be useful.

Does anyone know how I might receive this callback so I can handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse provides a ["cancel"](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/cancel) method on all PFQueries, including the one in PFQueryTableViewController. In theory, you could cancel your query after a timeout of your choosing. Unfortunately, many developers are [reporting a bug](https://www.parse.com/questions/cancel-pfquery) in that method that prevents it from working.

My best recommendation recommendation is to check for internet connection before firing your query. Apple's Reachability project is a great tool for this.